# Pass variables to text boxes in C# WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Pivotelement, so a Windows Phone Site with multiple sites and on every site should stand 5 menus. I have a List in which there every 5 menus and each menu of each site must be in a textbox:

```
//Site 1
textbox1_site1.text = list[0].menu1;
textbox2_site1.text = list[0].menu2;
...
//Site 2
textbox1_site2.text = list[1].menu1;
textbox2_site2.text = list[1].menu2;
...
//Site 3
textbox1_site3.text = list[2].menu1;
...
```

Here is where my list comes from.

```
public class Menus
{
    public date Datum { get; set; }
    public string menu1 { get; set; }
    public string menu2 { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class list
{
    public List<Menus> list { get; set; } 
}
```

And I don't get it. how can I shorten this up in a loop like:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    textbox[i+1]_site[i+1] = list[i].menu1;
    ...
}
```

I know it's a beginner question and it's a little bit dumb but I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand you have a list of values and want to display each value in a textbox. you can do this with a little data binding. You need to set the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl to your data source (the list of values). After this all you have to do is modify the ItemsControl.ItemTemplate property. See if the code below helps. As you can see, everything is in the code-behind to keep it short.

```
//in ctor, after InitializeComponents()
DataContext = this;
//create the source of data (values to display in text boxes)
public List<string> Data{
    get{
        return new List<string>(){"item1", "item2"};
    }
}
```

the rest is in the xaml file. Create an ItemsControl the gets the data from the Data property and displays it.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

this should solve your problem

Comment: I know I can do it with data binding. But I have 5 different sites with 5 Listbox. I edited my question.

Comment: sorry, but i can't understand very much from the first 2 lines of your post. i don't know if it's the english or the phrasing. can you rephrase? or explain better what you want to achieve?